# flutter Navigator.of(context).restorablePushNamed is not returning future and any result

Tags: flutter

Navigator.of(context).restorablePushNamed is not returning future and not returning and valid result,
IDEA IDE shows this method does not return any future but your documentation shows it return future.
here is your documentation
[enter link description here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/restorablePushNamed.html)

My code for push and pop is

for push :

final result =  Navigator.of(context).restorablePushNamed('/demo/lists');

for pop :

Navigator.pop(context, 'yo');

So when I run it, and print the result it gives me r+3, r+4

Comment: Have you tried to put `await` in front of `Navigator.of(context).restorablePushNamed('/demo/lists');` ?

Comment: *"... but your documentation shows it return future."*, the official documentation says it returns a `String`